# The best way for Servlet and JSP communication

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, epoch.js

following scneraion:

I have an  `java.sql.ResultSet` `rs` in my `Servlet`. Now I want to make a chart (using epoch https://fastly.github.io/epoch/getting-started/).

The chart js needs the data to be in the following format:

`var data = [
  { label: 'Layer 1', values: [ {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 2} ] },
  { label: 'Layer 2', values: [ {x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}, {x: 2, y: 4} ] }
];`

Right now, my `ResultSet` looks like this:

`x,y`

`x,y`

...

How should the communication between the `Servlet` and the `JSP` be? Should I just send the `ResultSet` `obejct` to the JSP and convert it there or should I convert it in the Servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would at minimum extract the data from the `ResultSet` into a `Collection` (e.g. `List`) and work with that in JSP (using JSTL).

But if it's an option I'd seriously consider dropping the JSP altogether and reimplementing the servlet as a REST service which you invoke from the Javascript on the client (and return the data as JSON directly from the servlet).

edit: To expand on the second option, you can convert your data to a JSON string (either manually or using a library like Jackson - [see here for an example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)) and then put that string in the servlet response.

Then from the Javascript you can invoke the servlet. I don't know what frameworks you're using but you can do it with a few lines of jquery (see [jquery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/))

Comment: Can you explain the second option a little bit more?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, Servlets should never reference a ResultSet. You should encapsulate this logic into a service which can be tested, mocked, intercepted etc etc.

Eg

```
public class Series {
    private String label;
    private List<Point> points;

    // getters and setters
}

public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    // getters and setters
}

public interface ChartService {
    List<Series> getAverageRainfall(Date from, Date to);
}

public class ChartServiceImpl implements ChartService {
    public List<Series> getAverageRainfall(Date from, Date to) {
        // here is where you might reference java.sql.ResultSet
    }
}
```

This could then easily be turned into a http endpoint which returns json using [spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) or similar meaning you wouldn't actually need a custom servlet.